# Allow single user per action method MVC 4.0 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, concurrency

A transaction is being performed on one MVc 4.0 web-page for a given task with Task ID: XX. Other user cannot perform the same transaction from anywhere if this transaction/record is under edit mode by first user.

I understand it that if some user is opened the page for edit, another user can not access the same page for the given task/transaction id(primary key in edit mode).

I have tried Optimistic Concurrency but it warns the user during the save/edit click, as for my requirement user should not allow to open the page if its already in edit mode.

I thought to write action filter that stores the task id in session.. Is it the correct way to implement this?

How to allow only single user at a time to execute the action method ?

Comment: you would need to store it globally across the thread using the Application object, however, if you put it behind a webfarm, or create a web garden, you will still get the concurrency issue.  i would go with marking the record as being in edit before allowing the user to see the edit page and returning them to another page if it is being edited.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want pessimistic concurrency, not optimistic.

You need to roll this yourself, making sure to only allow a user to edit a record after they have obtained a lock:

- Check out the [Pessimistic Offline Lock pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pessimisticOfflineLock.html) as described by Martin Fowler.
- Then take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617934/how-do-i-implement-pessimistic-locking-in-an-asp-net-application) on how to implement it in ASP.NET.

Comment: I have added the IsLocked, LockedBy and LockedDateTime fields to the database table, and wrote MVC Action filter attribute that have logic to get these fields and check the lock against the record. Thank you @Ergwun and slicksim for the help.