# Lock web object among users in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net mvc site where users can select a number of objects, they are identified by a unique id.
What I would like to do is:

1. User A opens an object
2. When user B tries to open the same object, a message will appear saying this is already open by user A, therefore is inaccessible.

I guess the server would have a sort of 'shared' session that can be queried in every Ajax request, to check if the object is already open by a different user. When the object is closed then that id should be removed from the shared list of opened objects. What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: What are these objects? CLR objects? database records?

Comment: I guess that doesn't matter, I have a list of divs that represent my objects, and when the user A accesses one of them, I want to stop user B to do the same

Comment: In general there are two approaches to handling multiple updates to the same object - optimistic concurrency and pessimistic concurrency. You are trying to implement pessimistic concurrency.

This is a good post on it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617934/how-do-i-implement-pessimistic-locking-in-an-asp-net-application Here

Comment: Here is another good post on locking - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114262/ways-of-doing-locking-in-NET-Pessimistic-and-opt

Comment: I don't think that'll work for me, I'm looking for a way to hold every open object id in Session - along with a timestamp. So that when a new request comes in it will know the object is being accessed by another user. I think the solution will include javascript and server side session handling

Comment: There's no reason to down vote the question, that too without a valid reason, it is against stack overflow courtesy. Up voted to counter

Comment: One way to implement this (and without keys) would be to give each of your divs a custom data attribute holding a `1 << n` value (where n >= 0). At every access, you can compute the state (by bitwise `OR`ing all the flags) and persisting to other users such that when a different user tries to access a div, if the `state & (1 << n) == (1 << n)`, you can block access. In other words you are managing the state of the system as a whole instead of each div individually. However the downside is you can have up to 53 divs before you need an `unsigned long` library for JS. This is usually very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a typical scenario, assuming that you are working with plain CLR objects, this could be a solution

// User1 and User2 are trying to access objectA

```
private static int objectACounter; // Counter to decide whether object A is occupied

if(objectACounter != 0) // Object A is occupied
  return user message object A is occupied

lock(objectA)
{
objectACounter ++;

// User logic processing

objectACounter --;
}
```

Above mentioned solution can be further refined by using a static dictionary to suggest which user has currently locked the object A and at what time, which can be returned to the incoming user.

In this case you plan to use something like Shared session, in my understanding there's nothing like a shared session, since session is user specific, above mentioned mechanism is a way to create one. You can plan to use Application Cache instead, where for each object you can define a key for each object and add the details in same way as you would do to the static dictionary, since Cache is a key value pair and it persist across the multiple user requests on the server.

Logic will be something like:

```
if(Cache.ContainsKey(objectAKey))
// Return error to the incoming user with details of object holding user

lock(objectA)
{
Cache.Insert(objectAKey, UserValues);

// User1 logic processing

Cache.Remove(objectAKey, UserValues);
}
```

Please let me know if I have misunderstood your question and you are expecting a different solution, We can adapt the current solution in multiple scenarios

Comment: Avoid using static variables; you won't be able to scale to a web farm or cloud in most instances, if/when the time comes.

Comment: @arao6 Agreed, then a Cache like NCache is a solution which spans across a web farm and there's no issue with syncing across the servers. Static approach is more of a traditional logic, Cache solution is working on similar logic, though it spans across servers

Comment: I think all I need is the use of Cache, since this is shared among users

Comment: You probably want some way of time-releasing the cache. If one user locks it, but an exception or error prevents the unlock from occurring, how can the item ever be unlocked? Instead of locking a counter, we usually lock a nullable date that is a specified time in the future, and then release the lock if time has expired.

Comment: I think in ASP.NET you could add a SlidingExpiration every time an object is inserted, is this what you mean?

Comment: Exactly any object has to be locked for finite duration and after that it should be released, sliding expiration, absolute expiration are all meant for the purpose. In this case we may not even do that, just lock for the cache update, for all other users, just check the cache inside and outside lock and in case it bears time stamp for a different user, then incoming user has to return.

//Check Cache and return if it has a different user entry

lock(Static_Variable)
{
// Check Cache and return if it has a different user entry
// Update Cache for a new user
}

Comment: Why is the following throwing an exception (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)?


``Cache cache = new Cache();
return cache[key];``

Comment: This exception is a Null reference exception, you are trying to access a key which doesn't exist in Cache. Cache is for practical purpose a Dictionary / Name Value collection, it will throw an exception if you try access a key which doesn't exist, use ContainsKey instead to figure out whether key is available before querying the key. Let me know if the issue is different

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar recently, but what I ended up doing was to not prevent a second person from accessing a submitted application, but to notify them that someone else is currently working on it when they view it (passive feedback) and if they attempt to modify it, prevent them from doing so, either after the postback occurs and possibly rendering the UI in a readonly fashion (active feedback).

I tracked the activity of who was using what with SignalR, this way I could dynamically update the list of applications when someone accessed one for the first time, or release an application when they leave the page, without forcing the user viewing the list of projects to refresh the page to be made aware of the change.

I setup a signalR Hub in my code to track which project was claimed by whom. I implemented the tracking using ConcurrentDictionary class to tackle any sort of concurrency problems of modifying the collection.

```
public class RetainedApplicationsHub : Hub
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, RetainedApplication> RetainedApplications = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, RetainedApplication>();

    public static bool IsApplicationRetained(Guid applicationId)
    {
        return RetainedApplications.ContainsKey(applicationId);
    }

    public void RetainApplication(Guid applicationId, Guid personId)
    {
        var retainedSuccessfully = RetainedApplications.TryAdd(applicationId, new RetainedApplication{ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId, PersonId = personId});
        if(retainedSuccessfully)
            Clients.All.applicationRetained(applicationId);
    }

    public void ReleaseApplication(Guid applicationId)
    {
        RetainedApplication temp;
        RetainedApplications.TryRemove(applicationId, out temp);
        Clients.All.applicationReleased(applicationId);
    }

    public ICollection<Guid> GetRetainedApplicationIds()
    {
        return RetainedApplications.Keys;
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        RetainedApplication temp;
        var applicationId = RetainedApplications.Single(x => x.Value.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId).Key;
        RetainedApplications.TryRemove(applicationId, out temp);
        Clients.All.applicationReleased(applicationId);
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}

public class RetainedApplication
{
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

On my Application list page

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        'use strict';

        var retainedApplicationsHub = $.connection.retainedApplicationsHub;

        retainedApplicationsHub.client.applicationRetained = function(applicationId) {
            $("td:contains('" + applicationId + "')").parent().addClass("active text-muted");
        };

        retainedApplicationsHub.client.applicationReleased = function(applicationId) {
            $("td:contains('" + applicationId + "')").parent().removeClass();
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
            retainedApplicationsHub.server.getRetainedApplicationIds()
                .done(function(applicationIds) {
                    $.each(applicationIds, function() {
                        retainedApplicationsHub.client.applicationRetained(this);
                    });
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

On my application details page

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        'use strict';

        var retainedApplicationsHub = $.connection.retainedApplicationsHub;

        retainedApplicationsHub.client.applicationRetained = function(applicationId) {
            //do nothing, must subscribe to at least one event to have the OnDisconnected event on the hub register correctly
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            retainedApplicationsHub.server.retainApplication("@Model.RegistrationApplication.ObjectId", "@User.GetIdentityId()");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried a solution on similar lines for creating a custom cache using ConcurrentDictionary, biggest challenge that I find is that it leads to a solution which cannot be scaled across servers in a Web Farm, if the application has to be hosted on a Web Farm. In fact this leads to a process specific solution. For future expansion and scalability Cache would be a better solution, Though the notification logic that you have created using SignalR is quite interesting

Comment: True, I'm assuming a non scaled-out website. I would think you'd be able to substitute ConcurrentDictionary with something more distributed as well, maybe a hash in Redis or the like. Granted it'd take more code to handle edge cases.